# What are the regulations for crossing the Atlantic in a twin engine prop plane

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, etops, transatlantic

Are there ETOPS like regulations for private planes?

If the plane has the range (4000km+), can it do it in one go?

Comment: A prop plane would have a couple of choices.  The northern route: Canada, Greenland, Iceland, then England or Norway. Or the southern route: eastern coast of Brazil to west coast of Africa, like Sierrra Leone.   Lot of overwater time either way.

Comment: You say twin engine prop plane, then say private planes. Which one are you asking about? There's a big difference between an ATR72 and a DA42, both of which are considered twin props.

Comment: It's quite common to fly single-engine prop planes across the Atlantic.  E.g.. https://www.aopa.org/travel/international-travel/transatlantic

Answer (score 3):

Aircraft operating under Part 91 have no ETOPS requirements. ETOPS is only applicable to Part 121 and Part 135 operations. [FAR 121.161](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/121.161) only applies to operators of twin-engine turbine aircraft in scheduled airline service. The rules for Part 135 are in [14 CFR Appendix G to Part 135, Extended Operations (ETOPS)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/appendix-G_to_part_135) and excludes multiengine transport-category turbine-powered aircraft.